# Is it possible to get only recently updated Google Groups with Python API?

Tags: python, google-api, google-groups, google-groups-api

I have an API that connects to Google Groups and gets all groups in my Google Workspace. However I want to get not all groups, but only those, that were recently updated (new members were added or some settings/properties were changed, etc.). Is it possible? I do not see any "updated_at_time" properties in a group class. Maybe there are workarounds? Please suggest any ideas.